# Test VPS with terminal

Tags: mongodb, meteor, terminal, mup

I'm trying to deploy my meteor application using MUP and I'm having trouble connecting to the separate VPS running my MongoDB. The `MONGO_URL` is wrong. Is there a way to test my connection via terminal on my mac so I don't have to keep rebuilding and trying to deploy the app. This is a time saver question.

`MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://username:password@111.222.111:12121/my_db'`

Comment: Not sure how we can help you here. You know that your MONGO_URL is wrong, but what should it be?

Comment: If I recall correctly, mup has a command to update just the env not a full build. Regarding testing your mongo connection string - you could download the mongo shell. One thing to note is that depending on where your mongoDB (and meteor server) are hosted you may be able to connect from your mac, and not from your meteor server, or vice versa.